# Sigma notation formula $i=0$

Tags: summation, notation

I am trying to help a high school student to solve summation calculation problems. The $i$ value of most answers I found was based on $i=1$ like this:

[image]

Now, the $i$ value of our questions is $i=0$ (instead of $i=1$). Is there any ready formula available for us to solve these questions? And what if $i=2$ or other numbers? Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you actually understand what sigma notation means, you'll notice that starting at $i=0$ or $i=1$ has no effect on the answer for cases 2,3 and 4.

Comment: While I calculated one question like  i=0, n=22, and the sum of (3+4n) I got like 1078 but the right answer was 1081. That's why I ask. Sorry, I don't know how to type the equation here

Comment: Thanks @Lizzi :)

Comment: How can you try to help a high school student solve these if you yourself don't understand Sigma notation?

Comment: @StefanOctavian, you are very polite thank you :D. I don't mind any bad comments. The thing what I care is that the problem is solved. that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to make sure that you start/stop the sum with the same terms. For example, this sum starts from 7 and ends at 20:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{14}(i+6).$$
If we want $i$ to start from $3$ (say), then we need to adjust the function inside the sum, and the upper limit, so that it still starts from 7 and ends at 20:
$$\sum_{i=3}^{16}(i+4).$$
In general, for any "shift" $D$, we have
$$\sum_{i=a}^b f(i) = \sum_{i=a+D}^{b+D}f(i-D) = \sum_{i=a-D}^{b-D}f(i+D).$$
In your specific case however, for 2, 3, and 4 you don't need to change anything, since starting from $i=0$ simply adds $0+$ in front. For number 1, you have
$$\sum_{i=1}^nc=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c=cn.$$
This is true for any $n$, so if you want you can put $n=N+1$ to get
$$\sum_{i=0}^N c=c(N+1).$$

Comment: Thanks @LukeCollins. That helps

Answer (score 1):

Just use $i = 0$ in your image. Then for 2), 3), 4) you just add $0$ to your sum.
In 1) you add another c, so it changes the summation but it is easy to think about it. Try it yourself.

For $i \geq 2$ you can write it differently, e.g.
$$\sum\limits_{i=2}^n c = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n c - \sum\limits_{i=1}^1 c = cn - c = (n-1)c$$

Comment: Thank you @Lizzi. Your answer gives me a quick approach. Luke's answer gave me more details. Thank again